# Optimizing drawing of cubes

Tags: xna, c#

After googling for hours I've come to a few conclusions, I need to either rewrite my whole cube class, or figure out how to use hardware instancing. I can draw up to 2500 cubes with little lag, but after that my fps drops. Is there a way I can use my class for hardware instancing? Or would I be better off rewriting my class for optimization?

```
    public class Cube
{
public GraphicsDevice device;
public VertexBuffer cubeVertexBuffer;

public Cube(GraphicsDevice graphicsDevice)
{
    device = graphicsDevice;

    var vertices = new List<VertexPositionTexture>();

    BuildFace(vertices, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), new Vector3(0, 1, 1));
    BuildFace(vertices, new Vector3(0, 0, 1), new Vector3(1, 1, 1));
    BuildFace(vertices, new Vector3(1, 0, 1), new Vector3(1, 1, 0));
    BuildFace(vertices, new Vector3(1, 0, 0), new Vector3(0, 1, 0));

    BuildFaceHorizontal(vertices, new Vector3(0, 1, 0), new Vector3(1, 1, 1));
    BuildFaceHorizontal(vertices, new Vector3(0, 0, 1), new Vector3(1, 0, 0));

    cubeVertexBuffer = new VertexBuffer(device, VertexPositionTexture.VertexDeclaration, vertices.Count, BufferUsage.WriteOnly);

    cubeVertexBuffer.SetData<VertexPositionTexture>(vertices.ToArray());


}

private void BuildFace(List<VertexPositionTexture> vertices, Vector3 p1, Vector3 p2)
{
    vertices.Add(BuildVertex(p1.X, p1.Y, p1.Z, 1, 0));
    vertices.Add(BuildVertex(p1.X, p2.Y, p1.Z, 1, 1));
    vertices.Add(BuildVertex(p2.X, p2.Y, p2.Z, 0, 1));
    vertices.Add(BuildVertex(p2.X, p2.Y, p2.Z, 0, 1));
    vertices.Add(BuildVertex(p2.X, p1.Y, p2.Z, 0, 0));
    vertices.Add(BuildVertex(p1.X, p1.Y, p1.Z, 1, 0));
}

private void BuildFaceHorizontal(List<VertexPositionTexture> vertices, Vector3 p1, Vector3 p2)
{
    vertices.Add(BuildVertex(p1.X, p1.Y, p1.Z, 0, 1));
    vertices.Add(BuildVertex(p2.X, p1.Y, p1.Z, 1, 1));
    vertices.Add(BuildVertex(p2.X, p2.Y, p2.Z, 1, 0));
    vertices.Add(BuildVertex(p1.X, p1.Y, p1.Z, 0, 1));
    vertices.Add(BuildVertex(p2.X, p2.Y, p2.Z, 1, 0));
    vertices.Add(BuildVertex(p1.X, p1.Y, p2.Z, 0, 0));
}

private VertexPositionTexture BuildVertex(float x, float y, float z, float u, float v)
{
    return new VertexPositionTexture(new Vector3(x, y, z), new Vector2(u, v));
}

public void Draw(BasicEffect effect)
{

    foreach (EffectPass pass in effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
    {
        pass.Apply();
        device.SetVertexBuffer(cubeVertexBuffer);
        device.DrawPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, 0, cubeVertexBuffer.VertexCount / 3);
    }
}
}
```

The following class is a list that draws the cubes.

```
    public class DrawableList<T> : DrawableGameComponent
{
    private BasicEffect effect;
    private ThirdPersonCam camera;
    private class Entity
    {
        public Vector3 Position { get; set; }
        public Matrix Orientation { get; set; }
        public Texture2D Texture { get; set; }
    }

    private Cube cube;
    private List<Entity> entities = new List<Entity>();

    public DrawableList(Game game, ThirdPersonCam camera, BasicEffect effect)
        : base(game)
    {
        this.effect = effect;
        cube = new Cube(game.GraphicsDevice);
        this.camera = camera;
    }

    public void Add(Vector3 position, Matrix orientation, Texture2D texture)
    {

        entities.Add(new Entity()
        {
            Position = position,
            Orientation = orientation,
            Texture = texture
        });
    }

    public override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        foreach (var item in entities)
        {

            effect.VertexColorEnabled = false;
            effect.TextureEnabled = true;
            effect.Texture = item.Texture;

            Matrix center = Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f));
            Matrix scale = Matrix.CreateScale(1f);
            Matrix translate = Matrix.CreateTranslation(item.Position);

            effect.World = center * scale * translate;
            effect.View = camera.view;
            effect.Projection = camera.proj;

            effect.FogEnabled = true;
            effect.FogColor = Color.CornflowerBlue.ToVector3();
            effect.FogStart = 1.0f;
            effect.FogEnd = 50.0f;

            cube.Draw(effect);
        }

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}
}
```

There are probably many reasons that my fps is so slow, but I can't seem to figure out how to fix it. I've looked at techcraft as well, but what I have is too specific to what I want the outcome to be to just rewrite everything from scratch

Comment: Might be a micro-optimization, but you probably want to batch together cubes with like textures. I've never tried to draw that many objects, but I know that switching the texture (and I think just the general "pass.Apply" function) is relatively expensive when called numerous times.

Answer (score 3):

Are you trying to create a voxel engine (with grid-aligned cubes)?

If so:
Try doing face occlusion.  When you build a cube, check if it has a neighbor cube.  If, say, the block to the X- position is solid, then you don't need to build the X- face.

```
if(!blocks[x - 1][y][z].solid) { /* build XNegative face */ }
if(!blocks[x + 1][y][z].solid) { /* build XPositive face */ }
// etc...
```

[image]

If you aren't trying to create a voxel engine, and instead want to just have a lot of objects that are cubes, then yes, you will want to look into hardware instancing.  You can do so with XNA's GraphicsDevice.DrawInstancedPrimitives() method.

Comment: Ah this makes sense. I thought this was automatically done by XNA already through frustum culling or whatever its called. How would I implement this into my cube class tho? My cubes are added to my cubeDrawable list through a for method in my main class

Comment: The only automatic culling that XNA does for you is backface culling.  (Frustum culling also requires you to manually check if an object is inside the camera's view frustum)  To achieve face occlusion culling, you'll need to set up some method to access cubes.  The easiest way to achieve this is to have an array of cubes; what many voxel engines like Techcraft or Minecraft do is they split this array into chunks to allow dynamically loading/unloading chunks.

Comment: I planned to have different drawable lists storing different areas of the map. That should be easy enough

Comment: Is it possible that my vertex and indices buffer is being drawn more than once? It should only be drawn every time a cube is interacted with.

Comment: Relying on late-stage culling will never save you as much processing as never sending the face down the pipeline in the first place.

Comment: What do you mean by "every time a cube is interacted with"?  You have to draw the buffers each frame.

Comment: I confused myself. I need to store a certain amount of cubes in a single vertex buffer so instead of making a 40,000 draw calls for 40,000 cubes I'm making a few draw calls which draw chunks of the map

Comment: I'm still not quite clear what you mean; you have to draw the vertexbuffers of all chunks in view (you get to define what it means to be 'in view') each frame.

Comment: Alright I'll try to explain better lol. Right now, I have a vertex buffer for each cube. If I have 40,000 cubes, that's 40,000 seperate draw calls made per frame, which is not good. I want to store more than one cube in a vertex buffer, say 50x50x50. So that's 125,000 potential cubes, being called once from one vertex buffer. I just don't know how to do that

Comment: Loop through each block in a chunk, and build its faces according to my answer above.

Comment: So if my "chunk" is my drawable list, am I checking for faces before or after I add the cube to that list?

Comment: When you build each cube, you have to check the neighboring cubes before you build the face.  If a particular neighbor is solid, then you don't build the face facing that neighbor, because it won't be seen (it will be blocked by the neighbor).

Answer (score 1):

The blog 0FPS has an excellent article on optimizing using greedy meshes: [Meshing in a Minecraft Game](http://0fps.wordpress.com/2012/06/30/meshing-in-a-minecraft-game/)

The article reviews some of the basic ideas like culling presented by previous answers, and then describes a fairly simple system to greatly reduce the meshes needed for a large number of cubes.  While the middle of the article is math-heavy, there are concrete examples near the end including a JavaScript demo.  An additional part 2 of the article describes other possible optimizations.

Answer (score 0):

You should only draw the cubes that need to be drawn. I can't help you much on this since my experience lies with 2D mostly.

And you should never use you cubeclass to populate the world. If so your cube class gets iterated each gameloop probably multiple times (in update and drawing). If you just make a struct like this:

```
struct Cube
{
public int textureID;
public int health;
//or even
public byte health;
}
```

and then make a 3 dimensional array from that it will iterate through that many times faster. Within this iteration you decide what to draw and using the cubes[x,y,z] to where you are drawing it. Using bytes won't speed up the iteration but when saving millions of cubes to disk will save disk space.