# How can I determine if a cube is adjacent to another cube, and optimize its buffers if so?

Tags: xna, c#

I'm trying to optimize the rendering of a collection of cubes, (based on [an answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/58022/1430) I was given to [another question I asked](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/58020/optimizing-drawing-of-cubes/58022#5802)). I understand the logic behind occlusion culling, but I'm having trouble with the code.

When I create a cube, I want to determine if that cube is touching another existing cube, and if so I don't want to generate the redundant data in my vertex or index buffers.

I'm planning on making a method that I call from my cube constructor so that everytime I create a cube, these checks are made, and neither occluded face is ever drawn.

How would I go about this?

Comment: I've reformatted your question to (a) remove the need to visit the original questions for context and (b) remove the code dump, which I don't feel is warranted given the nature of what you are asking (and which serves to make the question more imposing, reducing the likelyhood that you'll get a good answer).

Comment: Also, it's best not to refer to other answers by order (as in "the first answer") because they aren't always displayed in the same order for every user. Link directly to the answer instead. I linked the answer that showed up for *me* as the first, and edited your question accordingly. Please adjust if that wasn't the answer you were thinking of.

Comment: Thanks. I felt that without the code, this question would be too similar to the other question I asked. I want a more specific answer based on the code I already have because I'm having more trouble with it than I expected

Comment: Feel free to put it back if you think it would be useful (ideally at the bottom of the question).

Comment: I'll see what kind of answer people can come up with. Hopefully I can make something out of pseudocode, but I'm not good at that lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're taking a very [OOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) approach to this problem, when really you should be taking a more [functional approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) (just the approach - we're not going "all-in" here - we're basically just applying functions to buffers).

Instead of a cube `class` (reference type) with a constructor that gets "created", simply have a cube `struct` (value type) with a *very* small memory footprint. This could be as simple as an `int` that indicates what kind of cube it is. The important thing is to, like an integer, have a "zero" value that represents an empty space.

Then create an array of these. For simplicity you can use a 3D array. Later on you might want to consider a 1D array (slightly faster in .NET) and trying to read through it while touching [as little memory as possible](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/870/288). But for now this will do - it is far better than allocating thousands of cube objects flung all over heap memory!

The position of each cube is implicitly defined by its position in the array.

Then, taking a functional approach, you transform that "cube" data into "vertex" data for a given chunk (or the whole world, if it's small enough). A method to do that transformation might have code that looks a little something like this:

```
for(int y = 0; y < height; y++)
{
    for(int x = 0; x < width; x++)
    {
        for(int z = 0; z < depth; z++)
        {
            if(x-1 >= 0 && cubes[x-1, y, z])
                AddFace(x, y, z, Face.Left);
            if(x+1 < width  && cubes[x+1, y, z])
                AddFace(x, y, z, Face.Right);

            if(z-1 >= 0 && cubes[x, y, z-1])
                AddFace(x, y, z, Face.Back);
            if(z+1 < depth  && cubes[x, y, z+1])
                AddFace(x, y, z, Face.Front);

            if(y-1 >= 0 && cubes[x, y-1, z])
                AddFace(x, y, z, Face.Bottom);
            if(y+1 < depth  && cubes[x, y+1, z])
                AddFace(x, y, z, Face.Top);
        }
    }
}
```

This takes advantage of the fact the cube data is stored in a spatially meaningful way.

I'll leave `AddFace` as an exercise. But basically it should append appropriate vertices and indices to a `List` of faces for the whole chunk. Which you'd then use to `SetData()` to your chunk's `VertexBuffer` and `IndexBuffer` (via `ToArray()`).

(As mentioned in comments in our discussion [over here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/58197/288), you can save yourself the copying that `ToArray()` does by using an array directly, instead of a `List`, and manually managing your count and capacity. Take a look at the code in [this answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/58081/288))

Comment: Hmm so the addface method is the challenged here. I need to figure out which vertices or indices are for each face, and then save the faces as Bottom or Top. The constructor would just be something like AddFace(Vector3 Position, Face) or whatever face will be

Comment: Ok I tried and had no luck. I understand what you're saying and I know how to set the data for the buffers, but I'm confusing myself with all the veritces and indices. Should I use an enum for the faces? and set each face equal to a vertex and index?

Comment: Alright so enumerations don't work for this...is it possible to just take the values from the arrays I already have and add them into a vertex and index buffer list?

Comment: I've thought about it for a bit and I think it's a good idea to get rid of my cube and cubedrawable classes and use a struct like you said. I'd only need one class for loading my map that way

Comment: In my code I have assumed that `Face` is an `enum`, and that the `AddFace` method contains some kind of `switch` statement in it that creates the appropriate *kind* of face around the given position. But this method signature was only for illustration only (as was the way `cubes[]` is implicitly castable to boolean). You can certainly modify it to suit your needs.

Comment: (Although, come to think of it, you could make `Face.Whatever` be an object with an appropriate prototypical set of vertices and indices. You could then use a little bit of addition and append the resulting values to your vertex/index lists. There are many ways to go about doing this.)

Comment: I only thought you could use certain values for an enum. That's why I gave that idea up. Using one would be a lot easier

Comment: The only thing I can think of is taking each face from the vertices and indices array and putting them into their own array, but that won't work. I'm so lost lol

Comment: There are only 6 possible sides for a cube, so an enum with those 6 values would be sufficient. The `AddFace` method would then have 6 code paths (a `switch` statement) for setting vertex positions, one for each side. If necessary, ask a new question on how to implement an "AddFace" method that does what you want. But maybe first look at the `AddQuad` method in [this answer](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/58081/288), and see if that helps you figure it out.